# how to access value of variable which exists inside of click handler, and store outside of it in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-lists

Question may sound tricky because I'm new in JS programming. First let me show you code,

```
<ul id="myid4" class="c_select_ul">
  <li>
   <div class="option op_cl">
     <div class="color"></div>
       <p>White</p>
     </div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="option op_cl">
    <div class="color black"></div>
     <p>Black</p>
   </div>
  </li>                                  
</ul>
```

and JS code is

```
        $("ul[id*=myid4] li").click(function () {
          var color = $(this).text();
          color = color.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            console.log(color);
        });
```

So what I want do is, access the value of variable "color" outside of click handler and and store in another variable. It can be logged inside of it as I have shown in code. I want to use it in other functions also like to send with ajax call.
I can make ajax call inside of it but, I have three other selections to make in same way and send the four values via ajax call and receive result.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is about the scope of the variable, Global vs local variable. You have declared variable inside the callback of click event, so it dies once the execution is over.
To solve this, you need to declare variable globally. You can declare that outside the callback handler.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="myid4" class="c_select_ul">
            <li>
             <div class="option op_cl">
               <div class="color"></div>
                 <p>White</p>
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
             <div class="option op_cl">
              <div class="color black"></div>
               <p>Black</p>
             </div>
            </li>                                  
          </ul>

          <button type="button" onclick="submit()">submit</button>
          <script>
                var color;
                $("ul[id*=myid4] li").click(function () {
                  color = $(this).text();
                  color = color.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                    console.log(color);
                });
                function submit() {
                    console.log('printing from other function-->', color);
                }
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, you can access the variable everywhere inside  the JS file.

Comment: are you using same JS file for other functions too? It will assign the valued only if click event is fired once otherwise it would be undefined.

Comment: i want to select it outside of click event same way i have to select two other options like type and model and when i press the search button i want to send these three values with ajax call.

Comment: and yes i'm logging inside of  `<script></script>`

Comment: Let me do quick debugging.

Comment: sure take your time

Comment: edited the answer. I have clicked on white to set the color to white. then clicked on submit and called another function, and i could log successfully.

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Comment: one more question if i click execute submit function without selecting any value it shows error can you suggest how to avoid that error and show alert instead of error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call AJAX once all 4 selections are made, use class selector instead of ID:

```
var state = {};

var handleSelect = function (index, selected) {
  state[index] = selected;

  if (Object.keys(state).length === 4) {
    console.log('All 4 selection are made', state);
    // Call ajax
  }
};

$(".c_select_ul li").click(function () {
  var color = $(this).text();
  color = color.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
  console.log(color);

  var index = $(this).closest("ul").index("ul");
  handleSelect(index, color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Jquery. You can also do sth like this.

```
window.color = ""; //notice the window.
   $(function(){
       ....
   })
   function myfunction(){
     $("ul[id*=myid4] li").click(function () {
      var color = $(this).text();
      color = color.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        console.log(color);
    });
   }
```